# svn won't let me update because of an outdated file

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm working on an eclipse project which I check into an svn repository using the subversive svn plugin.

I recently had to jump back a couple of revisions. Unfortunately now when I try to commit any updates, it refuses because it tells me that a certain file is out of date. How do I force svn to accept my local version of a file as the most up to date and thus let me check in my own work.

I tried to commit the individual file, but it refused, telling me it was out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to check in the directory itself instead of single file.

Comment: It won't let me do project level check in because it says my file is out of date.

Comment: not project level, but just check-in the package where your file is, make sure to pull in changes before you update the entire package

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: try deleting 'all-wcprops' file in the .svn directory where your file is located and try to checkin the directory then

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting an out of date error